# GTM - Trigger 60seconds after on first page and trigger on window loaded on consecutive pages

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a trigger in GTM that would trigger a chat widget (ex: Zendesk) only after 60 seconds on the landing page but that would trigger on window loaded for all consecutive pages.

I've been able to create the first page of the trigger using the built-in timer trigger but I'm not sure how to implement the second part.

Answer (score 0):

0. Chat widget is something that I would suggest doing through front-end. It's not generally expected  to see something like this residing in a tag manager since it has no relation to analytics.
1. Make a customHTML tag, attach your trigger to it.
2. Find out how the chat widget is supposed to be envoked. There's likely a line of JS code to open it.
3. Test that JS code in your console first to make sure it actually makes the chat pop up.
4. Paste the JS code in your customHTML tag make sure it's within  like so:

```html
<script>
your code here
</script>
```

5. Test it out.

Comment: The chat widget works perfectly if I use a normal trigger (Window Loaded by example).

My challenge is really to create a trigger that:
- Fires about 60seconds on the 1st page view
- Fire on window loaded on all consecutive pages